# Counting Selected Items of list boxes in VBA

Tags: vba

I have form with ten different listboxs, all of them have multiselect property, I am looking for a VBA Code to count the selected items of all listboxs on the form.

Because my search on net was working only with a specific named listbox that made the code long.

So is there is a way to make the code short and give me the total count of all selected items of all listboxes.

Thanks a lot for you help in advance

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/753849-vba-userform-looping-through-each-listbox-post3700714.html#post3700714) is how to loop through each listbox on your user form, and [here](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?51428-Count-Selected-Items-in-Multselect-Listbox&p=318900&viewfull=1#post318900) is one way to count how many rows are selected in a listbox.

Comment: Thank You Sir : I write the following code and it is working but not completely i want :Dim oneControl As Object
'
For Each oneControl In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(oneControl) = "ListBox" Then
       With oneControl
            Count = 0
            For intIndex = 0 To .ListCount - 1
                If .Selected(intIndex) And .MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti Then Count = Count + 1
            Next
            MsgBox Count
       End With
     End If
Next oneControl

Comment: i want the total count of all selected items of listboxs not for each listbox seperatly Thank you

Comment: That code is really hard to read, please format code properly when posting.

Without knowing more about your application, it's difficult to tell what you're trying to accomplish, but one error will be that your counter *Count* is resetting to zero in the middle of the procedure. Move that to the beginning.

What methods have you tried so far to make this work?